# How to delete non-ASCII characters in a text file?

Tags: python

I have this .log file that I changed the extension name into .txt file but it still reads as log file

[image]

but after I copied it and paste it a new editor and saved it as .txt file.. this is what it showed:

[image]

Somebody told me that it is a non-ASCII characters that I should delete. Is there any way to delete it or any way to copy the contents of a log file then place it in a text file using python?

Comment: This looks like UTF-16. You should probably simply `iconv -f utf-16le trendx.log >trendx.txt`

Comment: For the more general case maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609895/efficiently-replace-bad-characters (not the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you can specify the input encoding.

```
with open('trendx.log', 'r', encoding='utf-16le') as reader, \
     open('trendx.txt', 'w') as writer:
   for line in reader:
        if "ROW" in line:
           writer.write(line)
```

I have obviously copied over some stuff from your earlier questions. Kudos for finally identifying the actual problem.

Notice in particular how we avoid reading the entire file into memory and instead processing a line at a time.

Comment: but it only prints 3lines

Comment: Do you have more than three lines which contain `"ROW"`? Or maybe take out the `if` to print everything unconditionally.

Comment: here is my log file please help me http://www.mediafire.com/file/idxhn1j4ev1wwl8/trendx.log.log/file this is my only problem :(

Comment: Not sure which "this" is your problem now, maybe ask a new question (perhaps on [unix.se] if it's not programming related?)